# Python flood fill algorithm north, south, east, west

Tags: python, algorithm, flood-fill

I have a question about flood fill algorithms.

I would like to fill a given field that looks like this:

[image: Field]

The user should give the starting position

So far I made the below code, but it just fills up and down and I would like it to fill in all 4 directions.

```
#given field size and markers
number_of_columns = 20
number_of_rows = 10
filled_marker = "x"
empty_marker = " "


def create_grid(number_of_rows, number_of_columns):
    grid = []
    for row in range(number_of_rows):
        grid.append([])
        for column in range(number_of_columns):
            if row == 1 or row == 8 or column == 3 or column == 15:
                grid[row].append(filled_marker)
            else:
                grid[row].append(empty_marker)
    return grid


def print_grid(grid):
    for row in range(number_of_rows):
        for column in range(number_of_columns):
            print(grid[row][column], end="")
        print()


def get_user_input():
    start_row = int(input("Enter the start row: "))
    start_column = int(input("Enter the start column: "))
    return start_row, start_column


def flood_fill(grid, start_row, start_column):
    grid[start_row][start_column] = filled_marker
    print_grid(grid)
    if start_row > 0 and grid[start_row - 1][start_column] == empty_marker:
        flood_fill(grid, start_row - 1, start_column)
    if start_row < number_of_rows - 1 and grid[start_row + 1][start_column] == empty_marker:
        flood_fill(grid, start_row + 1, start_column)
    if start_column > 0 and grid[start_row][start_column - 1] == empty_marker:
        flood_fill(grid, start_row, start_column - 1)
    if start_column < number_of_columns - 1 and grid[start_row][start_column + 1] == empty_marker:
        flood_fill(grid, start_row, start_column + 1)


def main():
    grid = create_grid(number_of_rows, number_of_columns)
    start_row, start_column = get_user_input()
    flood_fill(grid, start_row, start_column)


main()
```

Comment: That's due to your recursive approach. I would use a FIFO queue here.

Comment: Can you give the full code and inputs necessary to replicate your observed output? And also the expected output and observed outputs?

Comment: @kcsquared For me the code and the description were pretty clear. I agree it might have been more convenient if the example code would have defined fixed values. But just enter a value of `6` for start row and start column and you'll see what happens.

Comment: @Matthias I agree that the code and description were very clear. However when I put in 6 for start row and column, everything seems to work as expected for a flood fill -- the center area is fully filled in. Are you seeing something different? I can't replicate a faulty output.

Comment: Yes, in the end everything is filled. It's more about how this happens. During the process each step of filling the grid is printed so you see the different states. You can see that it prefers verticals (due to the algorithm), only switching the column after it's completely filled. And the question is something like: "How can I make this look more natural, expanding in all directions."

Comment: @Matthias I guess that's possible; if so, the phrasing is extremely confusing. I would always interpret `it just fills up and down and I would like it to fill in all 4 directions` to mean it only filled up and down and not left and right.

Comment: Hey, sorry if I wasn't clear. I'm still kinda new to coding in generell and english isn't my first language. I also just started python two weeks ago. I'll try to make my questions/post more clear in the future! :) But so far @Matthias helped me with his version. I'll do more research on his code! :D Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the recursive approach to an iterative approach using a a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque).

You will have to `import collections` at the start of your script.

```
def flood_fill(grid, start_row, start_column):
    locations = collections.deque()
    locations.append((start_row, start_column))

    while locations:
        row, column = locations.popleft()
        if grid[row][column] == empty_marker:
            grid[row][column] = filled_marker
            print_grid(grid)
        if row > 0 and grid[row - 1][column] == empty_marker:
            locations.append((row-1, column))
        if row < number_of_rows - 1 and grid[row + 1][column] == empty_marker:
            locations.append((row+1, column))
        if column > 0 and grid[row][column - 1] == empty_marker:
            locations.append((row, column-1))
        if column < number_of_columns - 1 and grid[row][column + 1] == empty_marker:
            locations.append((row, column+1))
```

The existing approach checked `row - 1` first and then continued to work from there and that means that it now handled `row - 1` again from the new location (so a full offset of -2 from the start) and so on.

Now we build a double ended qeue where we take the first element and add the neighbors of this element to the end of the queue if they match the constrictions. Then this task is repeated until the queue is empty.